# Vala `load_contents` error with large files

Tags: vala

I'm trying to **read the content of a file** (should be easy...) and **I have no problems until I try to read huge files** (more than 2 GB). I get an error that i don't know how to solve and I have not found any alternative way to read the content which works with huge files. This is my code:

```
File file = File.new_for_path (abs_path);
uint8[]  contents;
try {
    string etag_out;
    file.load_contents (null, out contents, out etag_out);
}catch (Error e){
    error("Error reading from file: %s", e.message);
}
```

The `content` should contains all the bytes readed from `abs_path`. But I got an error saying:

```
 Error reading from file: Bad address
```

I don't know why I get the `Bad address` error. The file exists. Another file with the same name but whose size is only 50 MB works well.

**Does anybody have an alternative solution to read huge files in Vala? Or knows how to make this works?**

> Note: I use the `load_content` method because I want the bytes (`uint8 []`), not the string.

Comment: Do you need the entire file in memory at the same time, or would you be able to load the file in chunks and operate on the smaller pieces?

Comment: I don't need the entire file in memory, I have to send the content of the file through Soap Message and I can make it in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, reading large files into memory can be troublesome and very slow. Since you're able to work with the file data in chunks, you can read the file a little bit at a time using a buffer like so:

```
size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
File file = File.new_for_path (abs_path);
Cancellable cancellable = new Cancellable ();
...

try {
    // Stream the file in chunks rather than loading the entire thing into memory
    FileInputStream file_input_stream = file.read (cancellable);
    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
    uint8[] buffer = new uint8[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while ((bytes_read = file_input_stream.read (buffer, cancellable)) != 0) {
        // Send the buffer content as needed
    }
} catch (GLib.Error e) {
    critical ("Error reading file: %s", e.message);
}
```

This will read the file in `BUFFER_SIZE` chunks that you can then send as needed via SOAP message, etc.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! This is what I was looking for, a way to read up to X bytes. This solved the problem.